# Hibernate Basic value types 'yes_no' and 'true_false'

Tags: mysql, hibernate

In Hibernate a lot of Basic value types. 
One of them is '`yes_no`' and '`true_false`'. And I was wondering what the fundamental difference between these two types?
I see that in the database for the type of '`yes_no`' written '`Y or N'` and from `'true_false'` written `'F or T'` and no more difference. Then why do we need these two types? 
Why can not we do just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a convenience for mapping legacy database schemas.

If you have a legacy database schema where boolean values are represented as `T`/`F`, you use `true_false`. If they are represented as `Y`/`N`, you use `yes_no`.